# Wordpress image slider plugin with previous and next image

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui-slider

I am developing a site and i want to add image slider just same as [this](http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancymoves/index.html#&slider1=6) in wordpress.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you done so far other than posting this question?

Comment: This plugin is not available in WordPress so, I need this plugin to use in my site...

Answer (score 0):

No issues u can download this plugin and u can include in your website.

then create a costume post type use title and feature image and permalink in more filed